# How to Zend Framework with Propel ORM

Tags: php, zend-framework, orm, propel

I'd like to integrate `Propel` with `Zend framework`. I've seen the integration of doctrine in the past but [this post](http://www.brandonsavage.net/the-adventures-of-merging-propel-with-zend-framework/) says it seems propel is done a bit differently.

> Propel has two things going for it already: the first is that `Propel` includes its own autoloader, meaning that I didn't have to try and force `Propel` into `Zend Framework`’s file system structure. The second is that `Propel` is designed to let you put it’s files anywhere you want with ease, so long as you update your `include path` properly. This made the process significantly easier than I had thought it would be.

But the post doesn't go into full details on how to finish it. I'm guessing I have to modify the `Zend` `Bootstrap.php` and `application.ini` (I'm using the latest `Zend 1.10.8`), but I'm finding it difficult to find a post on the latest version of `Zend` with the latest version of `Propel`.

Anyone can comment how to do this in the smoothest way possible?

another question: does `Propel` has a command line interface or do I not need a command line interface for propel if I'm using the command line interface of `Zend`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I havent use Propel outside of Symfony but from what i know of Propel but i would think something like the following would work for the runtime stuff:

In your bootstrap

```
public function initPropel()
{
   require_once 'Propel.php';
   Propel::init($this->getOptions('propelConfig'));

   // so we can get the connection from the registry easily
   return Propel::getConnection();
}
```

In your application.xml (adapt to ini if thats what you prefer)

```
<applicationConfiguration xmlns:zf="http://framework.zend.com/xml/zend-config-xml/1.0/">
  <production>
    <!-- other stuff -->
    <includePaths>
        <propelRuntime><zf:const zf:name="APPLICATION_PATH" />/../library/propel/runtime</propelRuntime>
    </includePaths>
    <propelConfig><zf:const zf:name="APPLICATION_PATH" />/configs/propel-runtime.php</propelConfig>
    <!-- other stuff -->
  </production>
</applicationConfiguration>
```

Of course this isnt really full integration as far as im concerned... but it should be enough to get you up and running without a lot of hassle. If its worth the investment to you on this project i would go ahead and make an Application Resource. Run a propel build and take a look at the compiled php array. Then map that to xml or ini and embed it directly in your application config file. Then modify your `initPropel` to handle it like:

```
public function initPropel()
{
   require_once 'Propel.php';
   Propel::setConfiguration($this->getOptions('propelConfig'));
   Propel::initialize();

   // so we can get the connection from the registry easily
   return Propel::getConnection();
}
```

If you wanted you could even not directly load the array as parsed from the configuration file but instead create a `PropelConfiguration` object and programtically set all your parameters, then pass that to `setConfiguration`.

As for the build tools, ive found integrating with Zend_Tool to be an ordeal so i tend to rely on `phing` or custom shell scripts for all that. Unless you plan on using Propel on a lot of projects its probably not with the time to implement this level of integration. I did it with Doctrine 1.x a while back and it took me a couple weeks to work all the kinks out :-)

Comment: How do I adapt to ini? I have no idea

Comment: @rodrigo: it should be a fairly easy translation since the structure isnt complex... i think you can parse the constants directly in the INI so all you have to do is use the key value pairs int eh correct section. Then again i could be wrong, i never use INI format. If you cant figure it out i would post a new question about it... youll get more of a response that way :-)

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried

- [Integrating Propel with the Zend Framework](http://devzone.zend.com/article/184)
- [Zend Framework and Propel](http://blogs.hivalley.com/jhansen/?p=107)
- [Integrating Propel with the Zend Framework](http://www.zftutorials.com/zend-framework-third-party-technologies/zend-framework-other-technologies/Integrating-Propel-with-the-Zend-Framework-l45.html)

Comment: Yes, They're from 2006 and 2008. Zend has changed a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I place the Propel library in "Your Zend_Project/library" with a folder called Propel which has the runtime folder in it.

I then place this chunk of code in my bootstrap.php.

```
protected function _initPropel()
{
   //require Propel Library
   require '../library/Propel/runtime/lib/Propel.php';

   //initialize Propel configuration
   Propel::init(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/orm-conf.php');

   //initialize Propel connection
   Propel::initialize();

   //return Propel Connection
   return Propel::getConnection();

}
```

My Propel config files are in the "Your Zend Project/application/configs"

You also need to modify your index.php file so it will find the ORM models you have generated:

set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/models'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

You place your models in the Your "Zend Project/application/Models/database" name which is set in your schema.xml by the xml property in "database name="orm"" tag.

Answer (score 1):

Just try to add init of propel to index.php file but BEFORE you set up autoload process. 
In this case Zend_Autoloader cannot interact with Propel autoloading mechanism.
For me it work fine, but i'm not sure it it a good design...)